# Trouble with friend in C++

Tags: c++, friend

Ah yes "friend" the most dreaded of keywords, not quite object oriented, not quite procedural.  Well here it is making trouble again, I have every possible warning I could think of on, and all the GCC can tell me is that read poly() is not declared in this scope (main.cpp).  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I've tried rearranging the code in read poly, but that doesn't help, no other function prototypes seem to change this behaviour either.  I just know I'm going to be hitting myself when I figure out what it is.

```
//main.cpp
#include "Polynomial.h"

int main()
{
Polynomial test = readPoly();
}

//Polynomial.h
class Polynomial
{
    public : 
    /** creates the zero Polynomial and sets the default output character*/
    Polynomial();

    /** creates the constant Polynomial c */
    Polynomial( int c );

    /** creates a Polynomial with one term c*x^d */
    Polynomial(int c, int d);

    Polynomial(const Polynomial& toCopy);



    friend const Polynomial readPoly();
    void insert(Term* term);
}
//Polynomial.cpp

const Polynomial readPoly()
{
    cout << "How many terms? ";
    int termQty = 0;
    cin >> termQty;

    int coefficient,degree;
    Polynomial newPoly;

    for (int n = 0; n <= termQty; n++) 
    {
        cin >> coefficient >> degree;
        newPoly.insert(new Term(coefficient,degree));
        newPoly.degreeCached = max(degree, newPoly.degreeCached);
    }

    return newPoly;
}
```

Comment: do you contrast object-oriented with procedural?

Comment: I think you should still declare `readPoly()` outside of `Polynomial` somewhere where `main` can know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend declaration declares a function to exist in the nearest
enclosing namespace scope, but it only makes the declaration visible
within the class or through ADL.  And since the function doesn't have
any arguments which use `Polynomial`, ADL won't find it.  Just add a
declaration of the function in the surrounding namespace scope.  Or make
it a static member, rather than a `friend`—in this case, it seems
more appropriate (to me, at least).  In that case, you would call it
with `Polynomial::readPoly()` (or just `Polynomial::read()`, since the
scope resolution says explicitly what we are reading).  Such static
members are probably the most usual implementation of the factory
function idiom.

Comment: Thank-you that fixed it, and yes that probably is more appropriate, but it's a homework assignment where that is the spec so I'm not going to argue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't declared `readPoly()` before using it.  You can re-arrange the source (some more) so that it appears above `main()` or better still declare it before use:

```
//Polynomial.h

class Polynomial
{
 ....
};

extern const Polynomial readPoly();
```

Comment: I believe it makes more sense to place the declaration in the header so that you don't have to declare it everywhere you need it.

Comment: @izomorphius The function is not a member of `Polymonial` so not necessarily.

Comment: @izomorphius: If the function needs to be accessed accross transaltion Units, then Yes it should reside in the header.

Comment: Is readPoly() not declared at the very end of the Polynomial class definition?  If not why not?

Comment: @awiebe Yes it is, but it needs to be declared in it's own right.  I think it does belong in the header file.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe I did not say it is necessary just said it makes sense. This function looks just like an input operator to me.

Comment: @izomorphius I reckon it does make sense if there is a reference to it in the header file; it *implies* it will be used in more than one compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

readPoly indeed is not declared in this scope. Add a function declaration in the header. The friend clause only tells that this function can access private members, but it does not declare the function itself. So in the main the function is really not declared.